# iOS APNS: Transferring Certificates

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

I had an app that used the apns with my account certificates .. the owner of the app created a new apple account and i should transfer the apns to it

I make the steps that i did many times but it's not working

I'm using Rails [rPush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) Gem for my server side and it tells me that the notification has been delivered but I got nothing on the phone itself .

Is there any specific steps to do so?

Comment: MAke sure that the certificate and the Profile are both from the new Account, You should replace the .pem file also from your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOllow this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

you will get a file named simplepush.php, add your Device token in the field of $devicetoken and your pen file and run the script if you get the notification then thee is no problem with your certificates